# Custom accessoryView inside UITableViewCell not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview

I placed a `UIImageView` in for the `accessoryView` in a `UITableViewCell` ala:

```
UIImage* dragHandleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rtf_icon"];
UIImageView* dragHandleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:dragHandleImage] autorelease];

dragHandleView.tag = DRAG_HANDLE_TAG;
cell.accessoryView = dragHandleView;
```

However, when the cell is displayed in the table, the accessoryView image is only visible on the first row in each section. After poking around, I found that somewhere between the tableview's `willDisplayCell:` delegate call and the display of the cell, the accessoryView's alpha property is set to zero. Is there anyway to prevent this so the image is visible?

Edit:
It appears to be done during the `layoutSubviews` call for the `UITableViewCell`.

Edit:
The full `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function is long and full of cases that won't be hit in this particular instance. The code that populates the cell is below:

```
cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
cell.textField.hidden = YES;
cell.textLabel.tag = indexPath.section * indexPath.row;
NSString *filename = document.document.filename;
if([filename isEqualToString:@""])
{
    filename = [document.document previewItemTitle];
}
cell.textLabel.text = filename;
cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
```

The following code populates the cell when the image is visible:

```
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.section;
cell.textField.hidden = NO;
cell.textField.text = [section numberedTitle];
cell.textField.enabled = canAddSections;
cell.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
cell.textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
```

Comment: How does your complete `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` look like?

Comment: Solved. Since those cells are editable, the `editingAccessoryView` gets shown. Putting the `accessoryView` into the `editingAccessoryView` proved solved the issue.

Comment: congrats for workaround. i'm sure there's a more elegant solution to this but why fixing something that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those cells are editable, the `editingAccessoryView` gets shown. Putting the `accessoryView` into the `editingAccessoryView` proved to solve the issue. Inelegant, but functional.